# Mvc3 webgrid paging and sorting not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have a webgrid which is populated with data from database, and im providing edit and delete functionality with edit functionality in popup...Im facing few issues in this

The first issue is I enabled paging and sorting and both are not working, the second issue is when the user clicks the Edit button a popup fires and user Edits the data and submits it and the changes are made to database but the grid is still holding the original data..

posting my sample code

```
<div id="grid">
@grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "gridTable",
        headerStyle: "gridHead",
        footerStyle: "gridFooter",
        rowStyle: "gridRow",
        alternatingRowStyle: "gridAltRow",

columns:grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("FirstName", "First Name", style: "colFirstName"),
        grid.Column("LastName", "LastName", style: "colLastName"),
        grid.Column("Country", "Country", style: "colEmail"),

        grid.Column(header:"Edit",format:@<text>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditDetails", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "editLink" })</text>,style: "colOperation"),

        grid.Column(header: "Delete", format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = item.id })"><img src="../../Content/images/delete.png" alt="" style="border:none;" /></a></text>, style: "colOperation")),
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.Numeric)
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `grid` as in `var grid = new WebGrid(` ?

Comment: hi david, i got it and its working fine now